# Hard Resetting alsa Configuration?

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, microphone

I just made mess with alsa mixer [this is why i made this mess](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163729/microphone-is-not-working-in-skype) . is there any way so that i can reset my sound configuration and at least my system speaker and heafones don't work at same time .

or is there any method from which i can re-install this thing and make my microphone working . with my headfone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my microphone not working.
All I did is type this - `alsactl init`
This command resets the setting to default.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i don't know what exactly done its shows me that .. hardware found and my internal speakers stops working

Comment: @Gaurav_Java same thing happened for me.. but it also resetted to the default config....also did it solve things for you?

Comment: Nopes it won't help me

Comment: If I type `alsactl init`, it says that the command does not exist. Do you need to have administrator rights (`sudo` ) to be able to execute it?

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked like charm