# Alienware - Webcam - Mic don't work

Tags: webcam, alienware

I have Alienware M14x R1 laptop. I used Ubuntu 12.10. Anybody know how can I install the webcam and the mic. I would like use with the skype, but the system don't find the mic and the webcam.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163729/microphone-is-not-working-in-skype) (gstreamer-properties related one)worked for me on m14r2.

Also, upgrading to Ubuntu13.04 solves this problem without using gstreamer-properties.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ran into this problem, I fixed it by updating the BIOS to the newest version.  You have to do it through windows though.  It's available on Dell's website.