# Where can I find an older Ubuntu version of Skype that still works with alsa?

Tags: sound, skype, alsa, microphone, deb

Since version 4.3 of Skype, [`alsa` is no longer supported](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Skype-for-Linux-4-3-Ditches-Alsa-for-PulseAudio-447402.shtml) in favour of `pulseaudio`.
I need `alsa` because [several USB webcams are known not to work with `pulseaudio`](https://askubuntu.com/a/236878/164341).

Where can I download the last Ubuntu `.deb` package version of Skype that still supported `alsa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to install Skype is from the [Canonical Partner repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository). The latest version there is still 4.2.

The advantage with getting Skype from Canonical Partner is that certain dependency packages are automatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

Download version 4.2.0.13 of the `.deb` file and install it. (The *Canonical Partner* repository is still at version 4.2.0.11.)

```
wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.13-1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.13-1_i386.deb
```

On 64-bit systems, one needs to be multiarch because Skype comes only in 32-bit on GNU/Linux.